# Why method used at mockito object don't show println?

Tags: java, mockito

So I want to println some strings. When I do:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.myFunction(myList, path);
```

It shows me:

```
somepath/ABC
somepath/DEF
somepath/PQR
```

But when I do:

```
MyClass myClass = mock(MyClass.class);
myClass.myFunction(myList, path);
```

It doesn't show me anything. Is it possible to return these string on mock object?

Comment: Does `myFunction` return strings, which you then print or does the actual function itself prints those strings?

Answer (score 2):

Since you work with a mock object, you can mock the behavior of its `myFunction` method, like this:

```
when(myClass.myFunction()).thenReturn("somepath/ABC");
```

Note that this will compile, only if the return-type of your method is `String`.

If you methods return-type is `void`, then you should not mock a return value, but rather call the *real* method:

```
Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(myClass).myFunction();
```

which will execute the `println` statements within the original method implementation. This approach has some pitfalls, though - there's a possibility to get a `NullPointerException` (or other exceptions) if the method *uses* some class members, which will be `null` for the mocked object, unless you set them to refer other mocked objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to return something when particular method is called on mock object:

```
when(myClass.myFunction()).thenReturn("somepath/ABC");
```